# Can incorrect pointer assignment trick for add “Extension methods support” to C++ be a _problem in future?

Tags: c++, pointers, extension-methods

My solution I gonna use to add “C++ Extension Methods” to JNI jobjects to make NDK code more readable like (Uniform Function Call Syntax) is:

- Subclass the class that I want to add extension methods.
- For invoking the “Extension Methods” make a pointer of type ExtensionsClass to point to OriginalClass - (Although the pointed object is’nt an ExtensionsClass).

The overload is minimal & we can access public methods of the Original class.

```
#include <iostream>

// Represents a class external to my source
class Person {
public:
    Person(){
        privateage = 20;
    }
    int age() { return privateage; }
private:
    int privateage;
    short anotherField;
};

class PersonExtensions : private Person {
public:
    inline int size() { return 5 + age(); }
    //NoFieldsOnExtensionClass
};

int main() {

    Person person;

    PersonExtensions* pE = (PersonExtensions*) &person;
    std::cout << pE -> size() << std::endl;
    std::cout << (*pE).size() << std::endl;

    std::cout << sizeof(Person) << std::endl;
    std::cout << sizeof(PersonExtensions) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Do you think that this incorrect pointer assignment, since “Extension Method” only accessed public members of extended class & extension class don’t going to have any Field variables, can represent a problem in the future?
The size of the object are the same.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This works only because you haven't added any data members to the `PersonExtensions` class. It is still breaking strict aliasing though, when you say that `pE` is pointing to something that in reality isn't what you claim it is.

Comment: Dereferencing `pE` is undefined behaviour, any speculation about what happens next is a waste of time.

Comment: What's wrong with just creating a function `personSize(const Person& person) { return 5 + person.age(); }`? Would be legally callable on all instances of `person` without any UB whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing in your question code is *Undefined Behavior*, so an especially an optimizing compiler might do really "fun" things with it. In other words, don't do it, it might break at any time even if it works when you test it. Only way to make sure it would actually work would be to examine the produced assembly code after each compilation to make sure it does what you want, and this is essentially impossible, so it is never safe.

---

You are using private inheritance. So for same effect you can just do this:

```
class PersonExtensions {
public:
    PersonExtensions(Person *person) : _person(person) {}
    inline int size() { return 5 + _person->age(); }
private:
    Person *_person;
};
```

---

If you instead used public inheritance (so you could just call `Person` methods through `PersonExtensions`), then you'd need to add a getter for `_person` (for cases where real `Person` is needed), and/or add delegates for `Person` methods (for so called static polymorphism).

Comment: `_person` could just as easily be a reference

Comment: @Caleth True, that'd be better. Feel free to edit. Or I'll do it later today if I remember.

Comment: Yes, performing wrapping was the first choice I made, then I thought it might be a performance loss and implement it as @cmaster says, function calls. But with the calls to function did not have the UFCS and the code was less readable. Then I look for more twisted forms. I will go back to wrapping as the cost in the performance is negligible.

Answer (score 6):

This is *undefined behaviour*.

Yes that can break at any point.

Consider overloading `->*` or something instead.

Or just using a free function.

If you really want infix notation:

```
template<class T, class F>
struct extension_method_t {
  F f;
  friend auto operator->*( T& t, extension_method_t const& self ) {
    return [&t,&self](auto&&...args)->decltype(auto) {
      return self.f( t, decltype(args)(args)... );
    };
  }
};
template< class T, class F >
extension_method_t<T,F> extension_method( F f ) {
  return {std::move(f)};
}
```

then:

```
auto size = extension_method<Person>([](auto& person)->int{
  return 5+person.age();
});
Person p;
std::cout << (p->*size)() << "\n"; // prints p.age()+5
```

here we don't have an extension method, but we do have an extension method pointer.

Comment: Thanks @Yakk I Don’t know/use this override never, must learn. Do you mean use it in PersonExtensions?. I Do not mention in the initial question that the Person class is external to my code. I Edit the question.

Comment: @JoaquínLuisMonleónIrisarri Toy implementation of an extension method pointer added to clarify.